# Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop disk mirroring

Tags: backup, raid, mirrors

I have just installed Ubuntu in a dual boot system with Windows in my computer.

This is my disk configuration:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0x0001b172

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048  981571583 980545536 467,6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       981571584 1953519615 971948032 463,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512
bytes 
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0xae69efbd

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048   31999999   31997952  15,3G 82 Linux swap /Solaris
/dev/sdb2        32000000  166000639  134000640  63,9G 83 Linux 
/dev/sdb3       166002686 1953523711 1787521026 852,4G  5 Extended /dev/sdb5       166002688 1953523711 1787521024 852,4G 83 Linux
```

I would like to mirror /dev/sdb into /dev/sda.

How can set it up without reformatting sdb2 as raid?